# Overloading Typescript function with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am having some problems trying to type a similar function as the one in the following example

```
type Type = {
  x: string
}

function func<T extends Type>(v: T): boolean
function func<T extends Type>(v: T | null): boolean | undefined {
  return true
}

const getValue = (): Type | null => {
  return null
}
let x = getValue()
func(x)
```

but I get the following message as it seems the compiler is trying to resolve the generic of the first function definition

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(v: null): undefined', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Type | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.
      Type 'Type' is not assignable to type 'null'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(v: Type): boolean', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Type | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Type'.
```

I tried writing a simpler version of the function in the online TS compiler. I am expecting that the compiler should tell me that it is a valid function

Comment: See [the docs for overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature).  The implementation signature is not a call signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with overloading functions in typescript is the **last function argument declaration**. Typescript *ignores* this **last** declaration **externally** from the function and uses only this declaration for typing **inside** the function signature.

The last declaration needs to satisfy **all** overloads, you can see this in the typescript docs for [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). The easiest way to do this is just to pass all parameters and return value as `any`.

```
function func(v: number): number
function func(v: string): string
function func(v: any): any {
  return v;
}
func(false); // still throws type error - see note with error below
```

> Externally you can **only** call this function with a number or string. So if I try calling it with `false` it still throws a type error. So this verifies that last function declaration is only used for the internal types so long as they satisfy all overloads. Also note that the error only refers to `2` overloads **not** `3`.
>
> ```
> func(false);
>      ^^^^^
> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(v: number): boolean', gave the following error.
>   Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(v: string): boolean | undefined', gave the following error.
>   Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2769)
> ```

But this method of typing to `any` is imprecise and provides very loose typing inside the function signature. A **better** way is to [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) each of the function overload parameters and the return value. So in this simple example it would look like...

```
function func(v: number): number
function func(v: string): string
function func(v: number | string): number | string {
  return v;
}
func(1) // no error
func('string') // no error
func(false) // throws type error
```

So in your case you could simply use this code...

```
type Type = {
  x: string
}

function func<T extends Type>(v: T): boolean
function func<T extends Type>(v: T | null): boolean | undefined
function func<T extends Type>(v: T | null): boolean | undefined {
  return true
}

const getValue = (): Type | null => {
  return null
}

let x = getValue()

func(x) // no more errors
```

> Yes this is duplicating the second overload declaration, this is not a mistake, this is required! Removing this duplicate declaration makes the code error as your original code. See reasoning for this discussed above related to the last function declaration.

See working TS playground demo [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8BQUoA8BcUDOwATgJYB2A5qgL6qoBmArqQMbDED2pUjLAPDFAiZgEUgBM8seAD4AFADdcMAJS4ARu3YAbCAENS9Jqw5cezfoOGiJUyHMWwoAHyikGWraqgbteri6YxCDoyCDFDFjZObiMLIRFxSTg7BSVnV3dPdU0dfXTA4NCxFHQoQghgBkIuIgYIalpmTgIocgqANV0tOqgkWS9k6Bc3D17pEoxyyuqMjwbUHWAsXtaOrrr+2jNZTGUoAHp913YoAFt2csFCQgu8IA)

> FYI - It gets much harder to satisfy all types when you have multiple generics and/or parameters/returns that are different for each overload declaration. At this point loosing the types with `any` (option 1) becomes a sensible choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a second overload for the `null` parameter type and an overload with the same signature as your implementation function to accept a `T|null` parameter.

```
function func(v:null):undefined
function func<T extends Type>(v:T):boolean
function func<T extends Type>(v:T|null):boolean|undefined
function func<T extends Type>(v:T|null):boolean|undefined{
  if (v === null) return undefined
  return true
}
```

Comment: Hi, that  still doesnt work if you pass a value of type T|null.

Comment: Hmmm, so if I understand correctly, you want some overloads with a specific type and one with the union type like your implementation? In that case, you can add an extra overload with the same exact signature as your implementation function: `function func<T extends Type>(v:T|null):boolean|undefined`

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your use case

Comment: Although if you plan to only accept parameters with a `T|null` type, you don't need to have overloads for your function